# xamarin xaml previewer custom objects not working

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, controls, preview

[I have been waiting for this 6.1 release for a long time and I'm really excited to start using the xaml previewer.  Unfortunately as soon as I tried to use a custom object it doesnt work.  Been trying for a while and I know it must be possible since James Montemagno posted a video showing a custom object working.  I've added a screenshot of a basic test.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!]

[Project] https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpSJU.png

[Extended Label] https://i.stack.imgur.com/b94Vl.png

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but it may be the extra space you have in the `xmlns:local` value. You have:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:xmlpreviewtest; assembly=xmlpreviewtest"
```

Note the space after the semicolon. Does it work if you remove that space? I am not 100% certain that whitespace is allowed or not, but I have never seen white space in that value before.